# Using CakePdf to turn a block of Html into a Pdf without a View file

Tags: cakephp, pdf

*Using CakePHP 2.6.7*

I have installed the [CakePdf](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf) plugin. I was hoping to be able to pass it the full html of a page and have it generate the corresponding pdf (in the same way [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) does). But when using the following code to get the pdf as a string

```
$cakePdf = new CakePdf();
$cakePdf->template();   // tried missing this out and specifying null for both parameters as well
$cakePdf->html($html); // $html is the full content of the page
```

I get a missing view exception for `app\View\Pdf\.ctp`.

How can I make CakePdf not require a view file?

**Additional error**

I also have the following error at the same time

```
Notice (8): Uninitialized string offset: 0 [CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 1001]
```

Comment: If you don't have a view, how are you supposed to generate HTML?

Comment: I wasn't generating HTML. I already had the HTML (or rather a user can provide it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else trying to generate a pdf from a given piece of html rather than by using views - the solution was the below code

```
$cakePdf = new CakePdf(Configure::read('CakePdf'));
$pdf_string = $cakePdf->output($html);
```

where all the configuration options have been stored in `CakePdf` variable of `Configure` in keeping with the documentation.